# css image being stretched to 100% height

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, image-size

I have the css no matter what I am doing its streching the image yet I dont see how the image is small but its making it massive height I am using

```
<?PHP the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );  ?>
```

The css used is the following but as you will see its causing[image] my images to strech and not be of correct size.

```
.services-icon img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
```

Url is here

http://www.lockmsiths.solitudesoftware.co.uk/#site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<img>` tag has a `width` and a `height` attribute set by Wordpress.

```
<img width="1000" height="500" ... >
```

In your CSS you can set an auto height to maintain aspect ratio, according to your `200px` width:

```
.services-icon img {
    height: auto;
}
```

Keep in mind, that your CSS overwrites your Wordpress settings for this image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width: 200px in your css, if you want the images use the 100% width in the container. The  tag has width and height attributes, remove it. If you can't control those  inline attributes you can use javascript and remove it.

Is not necessary use height: auto in this case, because the browser style apply that style. But I recommend you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the height to be automatically set with `height: auto;` in the CSS. It would be much better to change the actual image height in WordPress so that the `width` and `height` attributes on the image are correct (like @andreas mentioned).